# concise way to filter and map a scala sequence of tuples containing options

Tags: scala

What is the shortest way to transform a Seq of Tuples, e.g.:

```
val xs : Seq[(Long,Option[Double])]  = Seq((1L,None),(2L,Some(2.0)),(3L,None))
```

to a `Seq[(Long,Double)]` by removing the Nones

I've used both

```
xs.filter(_._2.isDefined).map{case (i,x) => (i,x.get)}
```

and

```
xs.flatMap{
  case (i,Some(x)) => Some(i,x)
  case _ => None
}
```

But wonder if there is a shorter way. For a `Seq[Option[Double]]` I would just do `flatten`... but this does not work for nested Options.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `collect` which discards what's not part of your cases:

```
 xs.collect{ case (i, Some(x)) => (i, x) }
```

In this case since `case (i, None)` is not used, these cases will just be filtered out.

Comment: great, never heard of `collect`, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
val x: Seq[(Long, Option[Double])]

x.map {
  case (a, b) => b.map(z => (a, z))
} flatten
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you'd call acceptable. Couple of options:

1. `xs.collect(Function.unlift(e => e._2.map(e._1 -> _)))`
2. `xs.map(e => e._2.map(e._1 ->)).flatten`

These are shorter, although we're entering code golf territory.